# UITableView Trouble

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

My navigation Controller 's Root viewController is UIViewController(rootViewController).
It contain's a UITableView, as follows:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c9b0985b63.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c9b0985b63.png)

When i press the arrow button(call the function in rootViewController), the tableview will move to left until only the arrow button left on the left edge.

But now i also want to press the cell to make the same function. But the problem is the  method  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: cant call that function in rootViewController. So how should make this ?

I guess use addObserver method, but know nothing about this , anyone can explain or give me some idea , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways: 
1.Make the "Map" view controller is the delegate of navigation view controller. Then in

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

call the `[delegate buttonPressed];` 
2. When the button was pressed first time, add a observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(buttonPressed:) name:@"flip_the_navigation_controller" object:nil];
```

Then when the cell was pressed, post a notificatoin:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"flip_the_navigation_controller" object:nil];
```

And remove the observer in `dealloc` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```